# Kernels can invoke a broader number of functions than shaders

Tags: opencl

I read a article which stated that "Kernels can invoke a broader number of functions than shaders" how far is this true.

link for that article is http://www.dyn-lab.com/articles/cl-gl.html

Comment: I think what the article probably should have said is "broader types of functions". But I still have no information on the subject.

Comment: @lucas ya even i am confused with that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is quite the opposite actually. If you compare Section 8 of the [GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.6.clean.pdf) with Section 6.12 of the [OpenCL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), you can see that there is a large overlap concerning mathematical operations.

However, GLSL has far more bit- and image-related operations and provides matrix operations which are not existing in OpenCL 1.2. On the other hand, OpenCL has more synchronization primitives and work group management functions that are not necessary with GLSL. Moreover, OpenCL provides smaller and larger integer types than GLSL.

Also, in Appendix C of the [AMD APP OpenCL Programming Guide](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf), the amount/types of available functions is not listed as a major difference between a shader and a kernel.